# Inserir imagem em um template blade do Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Como posso inserir imagens em meu template blade do Laravel? Quero imagens na minha página inicial mais não consigo linkar, criei uma pasta imagens dentro de public para armazenar minhas imagens.

Comment: Como você está colocando essas imagens? coloque isso na sua pergunta!

Answer (score 1):

consegui dessa forma, abri uma tag php usei o asset com os seguintes argumentos listados abaixo.

```
<?php asset('nome da pasta que criei'/'nome da imagem com tipo da imagem') ?>
```

Comment: Não é necessário abrir a tag `<?php`, basta fazer: `{{ asset('nome da pasta que criei'/'nome da imagem com tipo da imagem') }}`

Comment: Perfeito o código fica bem melhor, obrigado!